# Split window space equally in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a shortcut, hotkey, or any other way of centering the scrollbars which split the windows in vscode? Ideally I'd like to be able quickly recenter the windows, and ensure each has the same amount of space, but I dont see a way to do this inside any of the commands.

Comment: These split windows are technically called "editor groups", see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/custom-layout#_editor-groups

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This can be done using the `workbench.action.evenEditorWidths` action, you can either look it up in the command palette:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>
- Type `reset editor group sizes`
- <kbd>enter</kbd>

Or define a keybinding in your keyboard shortcuts file:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+a",    "command": "workbench.action.evenEditorWidths",
                            "when": "editorTextFocus" },
```